# How to interleave two files?

Tags: shell-script

How do I take two input files and create an output file that interleaves their contents? For example, if one file contains:

```
3 4 6 9 1
7 3 4 5 6
3 5 7 9 10
```

And another contains:

```
a d g e t u
v g j j u r
s f t u 1 g
```

Then the output should be:

```
3 4 6 9 1
a d g e t u
7 3 4 5 6
v g j j u r
3 5 7 9 10
s f t u 1 g
```

Comment: Have you made an attempt at a solution?

Answer (score 5):

You'd typically use `paste` for that:

```
paste -d '\n' file1 file2
```

You could also use GNU `sed`:

```
sed Rfile2 file1
```

With `awk`:

```
awk '{print;getline < "file2"; print}' file1 file2
```

(note how they exhibit 3 different behaviours when both files don't have the same number of lines).